# How to make IIS7 recognize specific file extensions?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, mime, mime-type

I'm attempting to embed .mp4 and .webm video files in a webpage and IIS doesn't appear to be recognizing the file extensions.

I read that I needed to add the MIME types for each extension in IIS.

I added .mp4 extension with a mime type of video/mpeg (also tried video/mp4) and .webm with mime type video/webm.

After adding the MIME types I restarted IIS using iisreset command in the command prompt.

No joy.

I've been testing functionality with a html file that links to the video files. I receive a 404 page not found error message when clicking mp4 or webm link.

I have tested the functionality outside the webserver root directory and both videos can be played /opened.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "I have tested the functionality outside the webserver root directory and both videos can be played /opened"? If the web server actually sent them to a web browser even one single time, then this is not a MIME-type issue (othewise that would apply *always*), but probably some configuration issue in your site's root directory (redirection, URL rewriting, etc.).